# Setting each value to a float, but returning an object in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, mean

```
for x in range(1,17):
    df.loc[(df[x]=='n'), (x)]=float(0.0)
    df.loc[(df[x]=='y'), (x)]=float(1.0)
    df.loc[(df[x]=='?'), (x)]=np.nan

df.dtypes
```

returns all objects. Why is that when I'm specifically setting each item to either a float 0 or 1 or a NaN. Basically i'm unable to run column means on this dataframe as a result.

Comment: I don't need to reset the index though. This has to do with the columns all taking on the object value instead of float64. I found a work around, but it still doesn't answer why the above outputs all objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/voting-records/house-votes-84.data'
df = pd.read_csv(url, header=None, index_col=0)
df[df.eq('?')] = np.nan
df[df.eq('y')] = 1.0
df[df.eq('n')] = 0.0
df = df.reset_index()
```

Result:

```
In [67]: df
Out[67]:
             0    1    2    3    4    5  6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13   14   15   16
0    republican    0    1    0    1    1  1    0    0    0    1  NaN    1    1    1    0    1
1    republican    0    1    0    1    1  1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0  NaN
2      democrat  NaN    1    1  NaN    1  1    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    0
3      democrat    0    1    1    0  NaN  1    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    1
4      democrat    1    1    1    0    1  1    0    0    0    0    1  NaN    1    1    1    1
5      democrat    0    1    1    0    1  1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1
6      democrat    0    1    0    1    1  1    0    0    0    0    0    0  NaN    1    1    1
7    republican    0    1    0    1    1  1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1  NaN    1
8    republican    0    1    0    1    1  1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    1
9      democrat    1    1    1    0    0  0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0  NaN  NaN
..          ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ... ..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
425    democrat    0    0    1    0    0  0    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    1  NaN
426    democrat    1    0    1    0    0  0    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1
427  republican    0    0    0    1    1  1    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    1    0    1
428    democrat  NaN  NaN  NaN    0    0  0    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    0    1    1
429    democrat    1    0    1    0  NaN  0    1    1    1    1    0    1    0  NaN    1    1
430  republican    0    0    1    1    1  1    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    1    0    1
431    democrat    0    0    1    0    0  0    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
432  republican    0  NaN    0    1    1  1    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    1
433  republican    0    0    0    1    1  1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    0    1    1    1    0    1
434  republican    0    1    0    1    1  1    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    1  NaN    0

[435 rows x 17 columns]
```

Comment: missing a `=` ?

Comment: Such a quick solution +1

Comment: but why aren't my columns in the form of floats to begin with?

Comment: @a1letterword, can you provide a small reproducible data set?

Comment: I'm using this dataset        https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/voting-records/house-votes-84.data

Comment: This doesn't fix the OP's issue (or the cause of it): the `dtypes` are still `object` after the transformation.